# How to determine the length of a string in a setter method and evaluate it in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, polymorphism, getter-setter

I would like to evaluate the length of a phone number string in a setter method. If the phone number is less than or greater than 10 chars a default phone number of "5555555555" is to become the phone number.

package Billing_System;

public class BillingTest 
{
    public static int current;

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    BillingItem Call[] = new BillingItem[10];
    Call[0] = new TextMessage(0,"86855536811", "5553381748", 0, 0.00);
    Call[1] = new VoiceCall(1, "8685553681", "5553381748", 450, "HIGH",0.00 );
    Call[2] = new TextMessage(2, "8685553681", "5553381748", 40, 0.00);
    Call[3] = new TextMessage(3, "8685553681", "5553381748", 60, 0.00);
    Call[4] = new TextMessage(4, "8685553681", "5553381748", 80, 0.00);
    Call[5] = new TextMessage(5, "8685553681", "5553381748", 100, 0.00);
    Call[6] = new VoiceCall(6, "8685553681", "5553381748", 2700, "LOW",0.00 );      
    Call[7] = new VoiceCall(7, "2125551212", "2123381748", 3150, "UNACCEPTABLE",0.00 );     
    Call[8] = new TextMessage(8, "2125551212", "2123381748", 160, 0.00);
    Call[9] = new TextMessage(9, "2125551212", "2123381748", 180, 0.00);

    for (BillingItem currentBillingItem: Call) 
    {
        System.out.println(currentBillingItem.toString());

    }
}
```

}

public abstract class BillingItem extends BillingTest
{

```
public int currentBillingItem;
public String CallerPhNo;
public String DestPhNo;


public BillingItem(String CallerPhNo, String DestPhNo) 
{

    this.CallerPhNo = CallerPhNo;
    this.DestPhNo = DestPhNo;
}

public String getCallerPhNo() //return weight
{
    return CallerPhNo;  
}

public void setCallerPhNo (String CallerPhNo)
{
    if(CallerPhNo.length() != 10)
    {
           return CallerPhNo = "5555555555";
    }
        else 
        {
           this.CallerPhNo = CallerPhNo;
        }

}


    public void setDestPhNo (String DestPhNo)
        {
            this.DestPhNo = DestPhNo;
        }
    public String getDestPhNo() //return weight
        {
            return DestPhNo;    
        }

    public String toString(){
        return getCallerPhNo() +" to "+ getDestPhNo();
    }
```

}

Expect Result:
Call 0 - From 5555555555 to 5553381748 was a text message of 0 characters and had a cost 0 TT$.

Actual Result:
Call 0 - From 86855536811 to 5553381748 was a text message of 0 characters and had a cost 0 TT$.

Comment: So where is the problem? it is unclear.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!
Please read and follow the
[Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)
please [add](/help/editing) 
a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: How do i get the array to be evaluated by the setter method?

Answer (score 1):

The setter method does not read from a polymorphic input. The user would have to manually input data for the setter method to be initiated upon which the setter method would evaluate the "if" statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are asking

```
if(CallerPhNo.length() != 10)
   this.CallerPhNo = "5555555555";
else 
   this.CallerPhNo = CallerPhNo;
```

Comment: Yes that is what i am asking.

Comment: @Dufeal Okay so is my answer right? Hit the Check mark next to my answer so others know that the question has been answered correctly

Comment: So are you happy with the answer, you know what to do know ?

Comment: Or do you want to pass the array reference to the method which will in turn change all non-fitting numbers to 5555555555 ?

Comment: @Harun Feraidon It is along the lines of what I want to do, but, it does not work as for returning 5555555555 when the phone number length is less than or greater than 10 characters.

Comment: @Dufeal I don't understand, the above code checks for the length. In pseudo code, if the phone numbers length isnt 10, which means it has to be greater or less than 10, then it changes the phone number to 5555555555, if it is equal to 10,  then it changes to phone number to the new number

Comment: @Harun Feraidon That is my expectation, but it does not return 5555555555 when the phone number is not a length of 10.

Comment: @FairPlay    
I will like to change all non-fitting numbers to 5555555555.

Comment: @Harun Feraidon Should i post the full class which is the getter/setter is in?

Comment: In the code I sent, Line 1 checks for the length of the passed in phone number. If the length is NOT 10, which means it has to be less than or greater than 10, it goes into the second line. The second line, now that it knows the length isn't 10, changes the phone number to 5555555555. Which is exactly what you want it to do......????????

Comment: @Harun Feraidon It should print 5555555555 if the phone number length is not 10, but, instead it prints the number that is already set in the array.

Answer (score 0):

OK as you posted in the comment section that you would love to pass array reference to the method which will in turn change non-fitting numbers to "5555555555" here is possible implementation:

```
package com.company;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] phoneNumbers = {"1234567890", "0123456789", "321", "911", "5678901234"};

        verifyNumbers(phoneNumbers);

        System.out.println("After verification phone numbers are: ");

        for (String s : phoneNumbers)
            System.out.println(s);

    }

   public static void verifyNumbers(String[] numbers){

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (numbers[i].length() != 10)
                numbers[i] = "5555555555";
        }
    }
}
```

In your case where you have an array of custom Objects you will use appropriate getters and setters in the method (loop) to validate and change number if needed.

Comment: It is for a polymorphism. So i dont know how to get it to evaluate  in the setter. I have uploaded the class to which the setter/getter is in.